# Can partitioning an SSD using third party software damage my computer if I am exceeding the space allowed by Disk Management?

Tags: partitioning, windows, disk

I am partitioning my disk to install Ubuntu as a secondary OS on my computer.

I have searched through other questions on askubuntu concerning what to do if Disk Management does not allow you to shrink your partition enough e.g. you have 100 gb of free space, but you can only partition 10 gb

The solutions usually indicate to use third-party software like gparted or Mini-tool partition wizard.

However, could I lose data if I bypass Windows' partition limits using this software?

For example, Disk management's maximum shrink volume is 10 gb, but you use software to shrink 50 gb

Comment: I remember reading somewhere in a Lubuntu post about how to increase efficiency.  It mentioned SD and overwriting.  In that post.  I may try to find for you... it said to make a buffer of x mb after each partition.  Maybe 20 mb will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether 3rd party software is buggy. To resize a partition with data the software should do a complex (and, in case of NTFS, never published) trick to move parts of file system away from the end of partition. Can it do the thing right? Who knows...

Answer (score 0):

Try this website below:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd

It wlll tell you some things to make your ssd more efficient and protect it from overwriting.  I did not try this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it wouldn't. Third party software just have the tech to relocate files marked unmovable in Disk Management.